# What does "play" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Just as there are those among us who are predisposed to develop physical strength more easily than others, mental strength seems to come more naturally to some people. There are several factors at play to determine the ease at which you develop mental strength:

What does "play" mean in this context?

Comment: "in action"  in this sense

Comment: "At play" is an idiom of sorts, in this sense meaning, perhaps, "associated with" or "contributing to".  It may perhaps have it's roots as an analogy to elements of a sports game, with multiple players.

Answer (score 1):

***[At play](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20play)*** that is, exerting an influence  on:

> being something that helps produce or influence a result - *Several issues are at play in determining the price of gasoline.*(M-W)

A related idiom is
***[come into play](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-into-play)***
also *bring sth into play*:
​

> If something comes into play, it starts to have a use or an effect in a particular situation, and if it is brought into play, it is given a use or an effect:
> *In the summer months a different set of climatic factors come into play.*
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I would say it means *exerting an influence* and not *exerting an influence on*. The "on something" can be put in parentheses to give a more correct grammatical definition: *exerting an influence (on something)*.

Answer (score 0):

**Respecting** the context and style of the sentence:

"Just as there are those among us who are predisposed to develop physical strength more easily than others, mental strength seems to come more naturally to some people. There are several factors ***at play*** to determine the ease at which you develop mental strength:"

**I would re-write it:**

“Just as there are those among us who are predisposed to develop physical strength more easily than others, mental strength seems to come more naturally to some people. There are several factors ***influencing (or affecting)*** the ease at which you develop mental strength:"